# unable to find goal using ros-navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, costmap, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i want to navigate P3AT (in USARSim @windows PC1) from ROS (Fuerte @UBUNTU PC2). **i am using ros navigation stack for auto navigation.**

**but after setting goal in rviz, robot just roam around left - right and start moving to random location.**

here are the files you may want to look,

**base_local_planner_params.yaml**

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  # for details see: http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner
  max_vel_x: 0.2
  min_vel_x: 0.05
  max_rotational_vel: 0.5
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.1

  acc_lim_th: 3.2
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 0

  holonomic_robot: true

  # goal tolerance parameters
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: true
```

**costmap_common_params.yaml**

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[0.305, 0.278], [0.04, 0.193], [-0.04, 0.193], [-0.282, 0.178], [-0.282, -0.178], [-0.04, -0.193], [0.04, -0.193], [0.305, -0.278]]
#footprint: [[0.075, 0.178], [0.04, 0.193], [-0.04, 0.193], [-0.282, 0.178], [-0.282, -0.178], [-0.04, -0.193], [0.04, -0.193], [0.075, -0.178]]
#robot_radius: ir_of_robot
inflation_radius: 0.6

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: openni_depth_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

**global_costmap_params.yaml**

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
  update_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: true
```

**move_base_params.yaml**

```
controller_frequency: 10
controller_patience: 15.0
oscillation_timeout: 10.0
oscillation_distance: 0.5

TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.45
  min_vel_x: 0.1
  max_rotational_vel: 1.0
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.4

  acc_lim_th: 1.0
  acc_lim_x: 0.5
  acc_lim_y: 0.5
  path_distance_bias: 50.0
  goal_distance_bias: 0.8
  holonomic_robot: false
```

**local_costmap_params.yaml**

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  # origin_x: -0.115
  origin_x: 7.5
  origin_y: 7.5
  resolution: 0.05
```

**move_base.launch**

```
<launch>

  <!-- Run the map server -->
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/map/map.pgm 0.05"/>

  <!--- You can see original move_base.launch -->
  <!--- Run AMCL -->
  rosparam set use_sim_time true
  <include file="$(find usarsim_inf)/launch/usarsim.launch"/>
  <include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_omni.launch" />



  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>


  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" respawn="false" name="slam_gmapping" args="scan:=lms200" >
  </node>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" respawn="false" name="rviz">
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195725/unable-to-find-goal-using-ros-navigation/) by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2014-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2014-10-24**:
Hi Sumant, you are not supposed to launch your SLAM algorithm (gmapping) simultaneously with your localization algorithm (AMCL). If you already have the map, comment out your gmapping node in the launch file.

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2014-10-25**:
thanks @al-dev for reply.
when i comment out the portion you have suggested it gives an warning,

```
**"waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error"**
```

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2014-10-25**:
I suspect you don't have any source of odometry measurements. What does your transform tree look like when you do `rosrun tf view_frames`?
AMCL requires that someone publishes a transform from the /odom frame to the /base_link frame of your robot. See the wiki : http://wiki.ros.org/amcl

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2014-11-17**:
hello @al-dev , thank you for looking into it, here is the transform tree, after i removed the SLAM [click to view](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r7h1it2h2uywcho/frames.pdf?dl=0)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. use gmapping to localize your robot in the map (use 2d pose estimate in rviz and drive around manually)
2. if the position is accurate (you see the estimate position in rviz visualizing tf) start your move_base launchfile
3. let us know your results :)

---

Originally posted by [lebowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/20622/lebowski/) with karma: 146 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2014-11-17**:
Thank you @lebowski , Result is still same, robot is roaming aroud!!, i m just wondering why it is happening.. Thanks